# How to reorder pandas dataframe based off list containing column order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Say I have a dataframe 'df' that contains a list of files and their contents:

```
File          Field          Folder
Users.csv       Age      UserFolder
Users.csv      Name      UserFolder
Cars.csv      Color       CarFolder
Cars.csv      Model       CarFolder
```

How can I reorder this df if I have ordered lists of how the 'Field' column should be ordered?

```
users_col_order = ['Name', 'Age']
cars_col_order = ['Model', 'Color']
```

So that the resulting df is re ordered like so (I am not trying to just sort 'Field' in reverse alphabetical order, this example is just coincidence):

```
File          Field          Folder
Users.csv      Name      UserFolder
Users.csv       Age      UserFolder
Cars.csv      Model       CarFolder
Cars.csv      Color       CarFolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put your new orders in a dictionary:

```
mapping = {
    'Users': ['Name', 'Age'],
    'Cars': ['Model', 'Color'],
}
```

Then, create a new column with those values properly positioned according to the `File` values, and make `Field` the index and index it with the new column:

```
original_cols = df.columns

for k, v in mapping.items():
    df.loc[df['File'] == k + '.csv', 'tmp'] = v

df = df.set_index('Field').loc[df['tmp']].reset_index().drop('tmp', axis=1)[original_cols]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        File  Field      Folder
0  Users.csv   Name  UserFolder
1  Users.csv    Age  UserFolder
2   Cars.csv  Model   CarFolder
3   Cars.csv  Color   CarFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with `ordered=True` !

```
categories = users_col_order + cars_col_order

df['Field'] = pd.Categorical(values = df['Field'],
                             categories = categories, 
                             ordered = True)
df.sort_values(by='Field')
```

---

```
File          Field          Folder
Users.csv      Name      UserFolder
Users.csv       Age      UserFolder
Cars.csv      Model       CarFolder
Cars.csv      Color       CarFolder
```

If you want to, you can always create a new column `Field_categorical` to preserve the original values in `Field`.